# Is there any automated [grunt] task to prepend a CDN to CSS/JS files inside your index.html?

Tags: angularjs, cdn, gruntjs, yeoman

Working with yeoman generator-angular, it assumes that you want to put your css and scripts files in the same server as your index.html file.  It generates a dist/index.html file that looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/7d151330.main.css">
<script src="scripts/6f9c9a13.scripts.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bd6ce9e3.plugins.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/ec88f033.modules.js"></script>
```

However, I'd like to host the CSS/JS files on a different server and prepended with the URL:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//mycdn.com/styles/7d151330.main.css">
<script src="//mycdn.com/scripts/6f9c9a13.scripts.js"></script>
<script src="//mycdn.com/scripts/bd6ce9e3.plugins.js"></script>
<script src="//mycdn.com/scripts/ec88f033.modules.js"></script>
```

I believe this is the YSLOW best practice and is in fact being used by the stackoverflow page you are currently looking at (view source to see their note on https://cdn.sstatic.net/)  Having different CDNs doesn't seem to be possible yet with the [grunt-google-cdn](https://github.com/btford/grunt-google-cdn/issues/30) plugin

My current thought is to perform a search and insert on:

```
<script src="[INSERTHERE]scripts/
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[INSERTHERE]styles/
```

UPDATE: There are several grunt plugins that perform a search/replace so this may be the best route.

Any additional suggestions to get a CDN url prepended during a grunt build?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same functionality and it seems like this package would do the job:
https://github.com/tactivos/grunt-cdn

Answer (score 1):

This does the job
https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cdnify
For the standard use case, just set a base string for your URLs – eg, '//cdn.example.com/'. The cdnify task will automatically search for all local URLs in your files, and prefix them with this string. (It will automatically avoid adding double-slashes.)

Answer (score 0):

For more general purpose than just "CDNize" you could use the grunt-preprocess module that allows you to preprocess your source files (html and else).

With this you can build source files depending on any variable.. like different URL by environment, DEBUG code adds, etc ...

More information here : **https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess**

ps: see an another related answer of mine here : [How to set AngularjJS base URL dynamically based on fetched environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969300/how-to-set-angularjjs-base-url-dynamically-based-on-fetched-environment-variable/22302117#22302117)