# Using grunt-contrib-copy for changing Test URLs to Production URLs

Tags: deployment, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm trying to figure out the best way of changing the URLs of files that are shared across multiple apps, from test URLs to production URLs upon deployment. I know that grunt-contrib-copy allows for regular expressions to be used to make changes such as these but I'm wondering...is this the optimal solution? Is there a better way of doing this? What approaches are others using?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Check an answer I made on a question close to yours :

[How to set AngularjJS base URL dynamically based on fetched environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969300/how-to-set-angularjjs-base-url-dynamically-based-on-fetched-environment-variable/22302117#22302117)

Basically, you can do this with Grunt and grunt-contrib-copy or grunt-preprocess ... It's up to you if you want to replace strings or pick the right config file..

Hope this helps