# Overriding the way how templates are retrieved using templateUrl property

Tags: angularjs

I am searching for way how to (at one place) override the way how templates are retrieved from `templateUrl` property (in routes definition, directives, `ng-include`, etc).
i.e. I want to change url of template for every template request by adding base URL at the beginning.

I was experimenting with template `$TemplateRequestProvider` but it seems it works only for executing directives and has no influence  for routes and its template retrieving.

Has anybody experience with it?

Comment: you could have a constant that you define in your run, and then setup a base url there.

Comment: I was hopping to have some default behavior to override and accomplish what I need without changing any existing directive/route/ngInclude.

Comment: well then you can use decorators, but i think that's making things complicated for no reason.

Comment: eg. https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing/wiki/Route-provider---decorators

Comment: I haven't tried but you could hack into Angular and force it yourself? Maybe add BASE_URL at this line?

templateUrl = (isFunction(origAsyncDirective.templateUrl))
              ? origAsyncDirective.templateUrl($compileNode, tAttrs)
              : BASE_URL + origAsyncDirective.templateUrl;

Comment: z.a. Yes, decorators are the answer even they are adding more complexity. However, it is still less complex than changing more bunch of code in our existing application.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change url of template for every template request by adding base URL at the beginning.

Use the following process:

- Assign the base URL to a variable in a JavaScript file
- Prepend the variable name to the existing templateURL values
- Expand the value via a build script or a provider

**References**

- [How to set AngularjJS base URL dynamically based on fetched environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969300/1113772)
- [ngAppRoot](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3102)